# Class is found on class path when compiling, but not when running

Tags: java, classpath

I've written a Java class which implements an interface specified in another directory. I compile the application like this:

```
javac ArrayQueue.java -cp QueueArray
```

The class `ArrayQueue` implements the interface `Queue` in directory `QueueArray`. Without the specified classpath, the compiler will throw an error as expected.

However, when running the program after that, it can't find the class anymore:

```
java ArrayQueue -cp QueueArray
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Queue
```

What could possibly be causing this?

**Edit:** The program works fine if I copy the `.class` files to the same directory as `ArrayQueue.class`.

Comment: Directory structure and package declaration?

Comment: Have you checked whether the .class file is present or not? You will require .class file instead during runtime.

Comment: @Thihara All classes are in the default package where the file with main is `ArrayQueue.java` and the used class is `QueueArray/Queue.java` relative to the main file.

Comment: @PranavKevadiya The file `QueueArray/Queue.class` exists and is about 250 bytes. It should consist of about 8 interface methods.

Comment: Then try to give the whole directory in classpath. Like SET CLASSPATH="DIRECTORY-TO-CLASS FILES" and then run.Then the command "java ArrayQueue" even will run without any conflits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be of help. From the [JLS, 3rd edition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/packages.html):

> An implementation of the Java platform must support at least one
>   unnamed package; **it may support more than one unnamed package but is
>   not required to do so. Which compilation units are in each unnamed
>   package is determined by the host system**.
>
> In implementations of the Java platform that use a hierarchical file
>   system for storing packages, one typical strategy is to associate an
>   unnamed package with each directory; **only one unnamed package is
>   observable at a time, namely the one that is associated with the
>   "current working directory."** The precise meaning of "current working
>   directory" depends on the host system.

It would appear that the JVM you are using does not support default packages unless they are associated with the current directory, aka the directory from which you are launching your customized queue class.

In general, its a bad idea to use default packages, my advice would be to associate both classes with a package, recompile, and retest your code.

Answer (score 0):

use `java -classpath . class_having_main_method`

Comment: Exact same error and to my understanding the `-classpath` option here is redundant.